# How to add multiple pdfs to zip file for download in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, zip

I have a controller action that creates pdfs.
I want to be able to get all the pdfs and save them in a zip file that the user can download.

My controller currently only handles the creation of one pdf, I don't know how to

```
def showpdf
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = Prawn::Document.new(page_size:  "A4",margin: [0,0,0,0])

        #pdf creation stuff

        send_data pdf.render, filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
      end
    end
end
```

I am able to change it to generate multiple pdfs but I don't know where/how to store them before zipping them up for download...

Answer (score -2):

Prawn allows you to save the generated pdf to the local filesystem, with

```
pdf.render_file "foo.pdf"
```

I would make a directory in a tmp folder (/tmp or RAILS_ROOT/tmp), build all the necessary zip files in that folder, then zip the folder (using a gem or a shell command) and then do send_data with the resulting zip file.

I would wrap it up in a class method, for the class of the thing which is having a pdf generated for it, to keep your controller clean.

Comment: Google it.  Like i say you can use a gem or the command line via shelling out.

Comment: I have tried that, I have an unanswered question here of adding pdfs to a tmp folder then zipping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028255/rails-add-multiple-pdf-files-to-a-zip-download